# Gaussian Measures, Bogachev, Theorem 2.4.7

Tags: pr.probability

In the proof of Theorem 2.4.7 of the book "Gaussian Measures" of V. Bogachev, the author goes from $\gamma(L-h) = 1$ to $h\in L$. I do not know why, could someone explain it to me ? I think that $\gamma(L-h) = 1$ implies $L=L-h$ but I have no idea why.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

In that proof, $L$ is a linear subspace of full measure; that is, $\gamma(L)=1$. If it were that $h\notin L$, then we would have $L\cap(L-h)=\emptyset$, whence
$$\gamma(L\cup(L-h))=\gamma(L)+\gamma(L-h)=1+1=2,$$
so that $\gamma$ would not be a probability measure.